# iloc[[0]] without printing the header

Tags: python, pandas

In https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html,

```
df.iloc[[0]]
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
```

gives header, `a,b,c,d`.

I can use `print(df.iloc[[0]]）` to print the 0th row, but it will include the header. Is there any method to print without giving the header?

Comment: Can you explain more? Each DataFrame has columns, if no columns it is not DataFrame.

Comment: In the above example, I would like to print as `1 2 3 4`, that's it. It's about printing control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need print values without header and index use [`DataFrame.to_string`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html):

```
print(df.iloc[[0]].to_string(header=None, index=False))
```

If need print only values like 2d array use [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
print(df.iloc[[0]].to_numpy())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! `print(df.iloc[[0]].to_string(header=None, index=False))` is what I need! You made my day!